# Mesh Deform using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm hoping to replicate the Mesh Deform modifier
but in a more procedural way in geometry nodes - so that I can use a cage object to distort my monkey, but without having to bind it like the traditional modifier

I've tried using a raycast node to kinda shrinkwrap it to the deform cage but it wasn't very accurate.. has anyone tried something similar or know the best method to achieve this setup?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, JaRa.. that looks more like a _Lattice_ than  a  _Mesh Deform_ , can you just clear that up?

Comment: Hey Robin, no it's just a mesh set to wire display mode so it's easier to see in the viewport, sorry should've clarified that. What I'm actually trying to achieve is on a much more detailed mesh but in this example I just wanted to show it in the simplest possible way to see if possible?

Comment: The binding isn't because Blender devs want to waste your time-- it's because there are calculations that need to be done one time, to establish a correspondence between the two meshes, and which need to be recalculated whenever topology changes.  Even if you recreate a mesh deform with GN-- it's possible, but a waste of time-- it will require binding.  If you want something that doesn't need to be bound, use a lattice instead, which just uses position in space to create that correspondence, so doesn't depend on topo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my basic principle example:

[image]

Besides Geometry nodes itself, I added some changes in scene. Firstly, I have activated [Rest position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/shape_keys_panel.html#bpy-types-object-add-rest-position-attribute) to get this attribute in Geometry nodes. Then I've added shape key and make it 100% active. Now than I edit mesh, it edits shape key, living "Basis" untouched.

So then it comes to node set up, it is relatively easy. I just find nearest surface position on "Cage" mesh and move vertices as much as Shape key moved.

This can be improved a lot, but I tried to keep it simple to make it clear:
[image]

Features that can be addressed:

- Use `rest_position` for *sample nearest surface*.
- Use *repeat zone* to capture more corresponding vertices and smooth out the influence.