# Non-Destructive Deformation of a Collection Instance in Blender with Lattice

Tags: python, modifiers, objects, geometry-nodes, collections

In my current project, I'm attempting to deform a collection instance in Blender. I believe using a lattice would be the ideal approach for my needs, but I've been unable to make it work effectively.

My efforts have included experimenting with geometry nodes, but so far, these attempts haven't been successful.
The primary goal is to find a method that allows for the deformation of the collection instance while keeping the option open to edit the original objects in the collection as needed keeping the deformation on the instance.

Comment: I don't think you want an instance-- an instance is only one copy of mesh data, so all instances' vertices have the same position.  You could use GN to make a *realized* instance, which you can then lattice; but, you could also just put the lattice on the original collection-- as a modifier, the lattice is non-destructive, and it's relatively easy to just reset the lattice to no-deform (like, pin a Basis shapekey.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution for that

This consists of 2 modifiers and 2 geometry nodes:

[image]

First modifier uses geometry nodes to get collection, and realize instances to convert to mesh, as Nathan already mentioned. Lattices are not supported in Geometry Nodes, so there is a separate modifier for that.

If you want to edit source meshes, you can just unhide collection and edit them.

You can also look at quite relative topic of mesh deformation: [Mesh Deform using Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305193/mesh-deform-using-geometry-nodes/305624#305624)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. In my project, I'm working on two different scenes. In one, I create building assets, and in the other, I assemble them into a city. Every building is made of multiple objects. In the city scene, I have an instance of the building collection, and this building collection is what I want to deform. The best-case scenario for me is to have a lattice that can deform the building but keep the option to later modify the parent without losing the lattice deformation.

Comment: So sorry, I'm an I-D-I-O-T and this does work.